# How to remotly tell my browser's addon to open URL from input?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, add-on

I am trying to understand what is needed to open a new window from a browser(chrome) add-on.

I have tried to create a chrome add-on with these settings:

my `manifest.json`:

```json
    {
      "name": "Action API Demo",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "action": {
        "default_title": "Default Title"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "windows", "activeTab","tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
      ],
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],
      "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"]
      }
    }
```

my `content.js`:

```js
    chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.type === 'addonname') {
            chrome.windows.create({url: "https://www.google.com", type: "normal"}).then(r => {});
        }
    });
```

I can install the add-on on the browser and my expectation is when I am trying to access `addonname://somemessage`

It will open a new window that goes to `https://google.com` but it just searching `addonname://somemessage` on google(default search bar).

What am i missing here?

Comment: Are you expecting `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener` to pick it up when you type `addonname://somemessage` in your browser's address bar? It can't be. Why do you think it works?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, so how can i send this message to my addon?

Comment: Thank you, its looks like this is not what I wanted, I want to have 2 way communication between my web application and my install add-on.
Is this possible to do? and if yes, can you point me to the direction?

Comment: In case you actually have a web site and need to communicate with an extension: 1) onMessageExternal must be inside the background script, not content script. 2) Content scripts can't use chrome.windows or chrome.tabs API. 3) Remove `permissions`, it's redundant for this task.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Yes, I want to communicate with web application, the question is how I am sending those messages through the website, can you refer me to some docs? I could not find anything about that

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage